# Coordinate System for 3D Flight Path?

Tags: coordinate-system, intersection

I want to build a algorithm (Matlab), which detects if a 3D flight path intersects with clouds (cloud=cube at first). Flight path waypoints are on a great circle and between waypoints I move on rhumb lines. I am struggling a bit with the use of the coordinate frames. Within the geodetic frame (Lat/Lon/Alt) I can define position well, but I can´t use vector calculation. With in the ECFS I can use vectors but I get issues with the 
curvature of the earth on long distances. ENU does´t work because the clouds might be bigger than 100 Nm.
I would love to have a system where I can enter (Lat/Lon/Altitude) and can calculate with vectors. But how do I manage the difference between rhumb line and great circle.

Does anyone have an idea?